# Omf and video guide track sample rate

Tags: post-production

I import an OMF into my Protools session. 
I match the session to the OMF spec of 48/16bit.
I notice that the audio that came with the video guide track is 44.1/16bit.
When I import the video track I don’t see anywhere where I can adjust the sample rate of the audio.
How do I do this or do I need to?

Answer (score 2):

When you import your video it will ask you if you want to import the guide track as well.  When you import the guide track audio it will automatically convert it to the proper sample rate to match the session.  You just have to point where you want the new guide track audio files to live.